# airflow GCS to BQ operator fails when JSON is the source format

Tags: python, airflow

I have a GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator operator running on airflow in a dag.  It works perfect when working CSV files...  I am now trying to ingest a JSON file, and I'm receiving errors:  such like:

```
skipLeadingRows is not a valid src_fmt_configs for type NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON
```

The weird thing is that I'm not calling `skipLeadingRows` in my calling.  as below:

```
 load_Users_to_GBQ = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
    task_id='Table1_GCS_to_GBQ',
    bucket='bucket1',
    source_objects=['table*.json'],
    source_format='NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON',
    destination_project_dataset_table='DB.table1',
    autodetect=False,
    schema_fields=[
        {'name': 'fieldid', 'type': 'integer', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
        {'name': 'filed2', 'type': 'integer', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
        {'name': 'field3', 'type': 'string', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
        {'name': 'field4', 'type': 'string', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
        {'name': 'field5', 'type': 'string', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'}
    ],
    write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
    google_cloud_storage_conn_id='Conn1',
    bigquery_conn_id='Conn1',
    dag=dag)
```

what am I missing?
Thanks

Comment: What version of Airflow are you using?

Comment: 1.10.5.  Was there a fix somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in this [pull request](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/5671) for Airflow version >= [1.10.7](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-5049).